# jQuery left to right animation positioning problem

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-animate

I am trying to slide a div from one end of the screen to the next, but I am trying to make it loop, so that once it has reached the right side, it will start again from the left and so on and so forth...

The problem I have now is that once the element reaches the right side, it loops, but the element just pops up in the left hand corner, where as I would like it to move in from outside of the browser window, to give it that seamless effect, here is my code,

Javascript/jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var body_width;
    var timer;

    jQuery(function($) {
            timer = setTimeout(Cloud, 0);
    });

    function Cloud() {
        //get the width of the body
        body_width = $("body").width();

        $("#move_me").css({margin:0}).
                animate({marginLeft: body_width}, body_width*5, "linear", function() {
                        timer = setTimeout(Cloud, 0);
                });
    }
});
```

HTML:

```
<div id="header">
    <div id="move_me"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
   #header {
        width: 100%;
        height: 250px;
        background: #000;
        overflow: hidden;
   }

    #move_me {
        height: 250px;
        width: 250px;
        background: #F00;
    }
```

Thanx in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just start the animation with the element out of the screen.

So you need to set its left margin equal to the negative width of the element..

```
    var cloud_width = -$('#move_me').width();
    $("#move_me").css({marginLeft:cloud_width}).
                 .animate(...);
```

**demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/XKVtC/

Comment: I tried that earlier, but it didn't work, I tried something like this `$("#move_me").css({marginLeft:-250})`, why wouldn't that work? Thanx for the help btw!

Comment: @user, your original code has `margin` and not `marginLeft`. That would cause a problem because it would apply to the top as well, and thus take outside of the container..

Comment: True, but before that I added the above in, and still it didn't work. When I try it now though it seems to work fine. :/ I must have missed something, thanx again!